# Calculating time until a ball fall

Tags: 2d

How exactly can I calculate time until a ball fall if I know initial and final `x` and `y` position of a ball, gravity, delta time, initial `dx` and `dy` of a ball and its speed calculated from the formula `sqrt(dx ** 2 + dy ** 2)`?

Comment: Which level of precision do you need? E.g. If you want to simulate a tenis ball with rotation/effects or just a simple, ball without atmosphere?

Comment: I want to simulate a small ball with no effects, without atmosphere. This equation should provide also horizontal motion, not only free fall with `dx` = 0

Comment: Downvoted as OP obviously did not make a lot of research before posting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing a macroscopic ball falling without atmosphere resistance and where Relativist effect is negligible.

- **P0[x,y,z]** is the initial position of the ball, with y >= r
- **P[x,y,z]** is the final position of the ball.
- **V0[x,y,z]** is the initial speed of the ball
- **g[0,y,0]** is the gravity, with y < 0
- **r** is the radius of the ball, r >= 0
- **ground** is defined as a plane at Y=0

The position of the ball at any moment is given by (1):

```
P = P0 + V0*t + g*t*t;
```

To found the time where the ball hit the ground (2):

```
P0.y + V0.y*t + g.y*t*t = r
```

Solving the equation (3):

```
t = ( -V0.y - sqrt(V0.y*V0.y - 4*g.y*(P0.y-r)) ) / (2 * g.y)
```

Final position can be calculated using (1)

Note: Considering that P0.y >=r and g.y is negative, the internal of the root is always positive.

Answer (score 0):

an unusual answer cause its mostly a link, but this is the way to calculate object falling according to X gravity following newton's law.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_for_a_falling_body